# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to update  the value of `project['submission']['status']` to `queued` for each matching version as below but running into a compilation error,any pointers on how to fix it is really appreicated?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import os,pymongo
dbuser = os.environ.get('muser', '')
dbpass = os.environ.get('mpwd', '')
uri = 'mongodb://{dbuser}:{dbpass}@machineip/data'.format(**locals())
client = MongoClient(uri)
db = client.data
collection = db['test']
print db.version

cursor = collection.find({})
cursor = collection.find({})
for document in cursor:
      if document['version'] == '9.130.39.0.32.6.1':
        for project in  document['projects']:
            print project
            print project['name']
            print project['_id']
            id = project['_id']
            print project['submission']['status']
            if project['submission']['status'] != 'queued':
                print "Inside Update.."               
                #project['submission']['status'] = 'queued'
                collection_projects = document['projects']
                #print collection_projects
                for project in collection_projects:
                    project.update(
                        { "_id": ObjectId(id) },
                        {
                            "$set": {
                                "sanity": "queued"
                            }
                        })
```

Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a95a1c32a2e2e0025e6d6e2"),
    "status" : "Submitting",
    "sanity" : "none",
    "version" : "9.130.39.0.32.6.1",
    "requestTime" : ISODate("2018-02-27T18:21:55.764Z"),
    "projects" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "BCMFurm_4364_B2_ekans",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a95a1c32a2e2e0025e6d6eb"),
            "submission" : {
                "status" : "passed", --> this status should change to "queued"
                "system" : "machine.com"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "BCMFurm_4364_B2_sid",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a95a1c32a2e2e0025e6d6ea"),
            "submission" : {
                "status" : "passed",--> this status should change to "queued"
                "system" : "machine.com"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "BCMFurm_4364_Notes",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a95a1c32a2e2e0025e6d6e3"),
            "submission" : {
                "status" : "passed",--> this status should change to "queued"
                "system" : "machine.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Notes" : [],
}
```

Error:-

```
  "sanity": "queued"
TypeError: update expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

UPDATE:-

```
'''
for document in cursor:
      if document['version'] == '9.130.39.0.32.6.1':
        for project in  document['projects']:
            print project
            project_id = project['_id']
            if project['submission']['status'] != 'queued':
                project.update(
                    { "_id" : ObjectId(project_id)},
                        { "$set":
                            {
                                "submission.status": "queued"
                            }
                        }
                )
'''
for document in cursor:
    docId = document['_id']
    print "docId"
    print docId
    if document['version'] == '9.130.39.0.32.6.1':
        for project in  document['projects']:
            print "project"
            print project
            projectId = project['_id']
            print "projectId"
            print projectId
            document.update({ "_id": ObjectId(docId), "projects._id": ObjectId(projectId) },
                  { 
                    '$set': {
                      'projects.$.submission.status': 'queued'
                     }
                  }
            )
```

Comment: `collection_projects` is a list, not a dict.

Comment: @StephenRauch - I tried that and updated my question but running into error `"sanity": "queued"
TypeError: update expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`

Comment: So now you sent update two dicts...  It does not like that.

Comment: @StephenRauch - Sorry,I didnt quite follow your comment,can you please provide specific guidance?

Comment: For `project.update()`  you are passing two dicts.  It is not happy about this.

Comment: @okay,any pointers on how to fix this?

Comment: Only if I knew why you did that.  What are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: @StephenRauch - I am trying to update the value of `project['submission']['status'] `to `queued` for each matching version

Comment: And what should `queued` look like?  It will need to be one thing if you are going to update the document.  Two things?  Not so much.

Comment: @StephenRauch - it should looks like `"status" : "queued"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following works,it should be `collection.update` instead of `db.update`

```
for document in cursor:
    docId = document['_id']
    print "docId"
    print docId
    if document['version'] == '9.130.39.0.32.6.1':
        for project in  document['projects']:
            print "project"
            print project
            projectId = project['_id']
            print "projectId"
            print projectId
            collection.update({ "_id": ObjectId(docId), "projects._id": ObjectId(projectId) },
                  { 
                    '$set': {
                      'projects.$.submission.status': 'queued'
                     }
                  }
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for project in  document['projects']:
        print project
        print project['name']
        print project['_id']
        id = project['_id']
        print project['submission']['status']
        if project['submission']['status'] != 'queued':
                print "Inside Update.."               
                project.update({"sanity": "queued"})
```

This will add the property `"sanity":"queued"` to the project in the loop. Is that what you want?

Comment: I tried that and updated my question but running into error `"sanity": "queued"
TypeError: update expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`

Comment: i updated the answer... so if this is what you need.

Comment: No thats not what I need,I need to update `project['submission']['status']` to `queued` which is not happening

Comment: so where does this "sanity" come from?

Comment: thats a typo,I updated the question,its actually `status`,please see my UPDATE,I tried 2 possible ways both of them throwed the error `TypeError: update expected at most 1 arguments, got 2` ,just lost on how to get past this error

Answer (score 0):

The value to the key `"projects"` is a list, not a dictionary. You need to `append` your new list:

```
collection_projects.append([
                        { "_id": ObjectId(id) },
                        {
                            "$set": {
                                "sanity": 'queued'
                            }])
```

And change the syntax as such.

Comment: But this doesnt update the sanity field to queued,the syntax error is gone but the sanity value is still not updated to `queued`

Comment: @user2125827 You'll need to iterate through each dictionary in the list and change `["submission"]["status"]` to `"queued"`

Comment: I tried that and updated my question but running into error `"sanity": "queued"
TypeError: update expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your document.

```
  var docId = document._id;
  var projectId = project._id;
  document.update({ "_id": ObjectId(docId), "projects._id": ObjectId(projectId) },
                  { 
                    '$set': {
                      'projects.$.submission.status': 'queued'
                     }
                  }
  );
```

This should work.

You can also iterate all the projects assign the status and at the end of iteration update the whole document at once, this will also work.

Comment: this doesn't sound like python syntax

Comment: this also throws the error `    'projects.$.submission.status': 'queued'
TypeError: update expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`

Comment: The positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first match of the update in MongoDB,

Comment: here is the link for mongodb update with $.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_

Comment: still doesnt work,throws error  `'projects.$.submission.status': 'queued'
TypeError: update expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`

Comment: This is the query i just run on my mongo console and it worked fine

`{"_id" : ObjectId("5ab37c0dc0c5e4c7bab4f6a7"),'projects._id': ObjectId("5a95a1c32a2e2e0025e6d6eb")},{$set:{'projects.$.submission.status': 'queued'}}`



o/p : `Updated 1 existing record(s) in 1ms`

Comment: Here is the complete update query.
`db.getCollection('test').update({"_id" : ObjectId("5ab37c0dc0c5e4c7bab4f6a7"),'projects._id': ObjectId("5a95a1c32a2e2e0025e6d6eb")},{$set:{'projects.$.submission.status': 'queued'}})`